# Unity - Components behind the scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, components

I want to know the programming concept of a component in Unity. I know that every GameObject like a Vehicle can have a component, and that every component has properties, like scale, position and so on. The component is independent, and can be attached to every Gameobject.

However, I don't understand the concept behind this! If I use my IDE and I make a class Gameobject and instantiate an object from that class, how would I do it with programming, that the object has a component. And if I change properties of that component, the behaviour of the instantiated objected changes too?

Answer (score 0):

## GameObjects:

A GameObject is an object in your scene that can represent characters, props, lights, cameras, and more. It is essentially an empty container that can hold components.

## Components:

Components are the scripts, colliders, renderers, and other assets that you attach to a GameObject to give it functionality and behavior.

## Example:

Personally, I prefer an example to explain what happens under the hood:

```
public class GameObject
{
    private List<Component> components = new List<Component>();

    public void AddComponent(Component component)
    {
        components.Add(component);
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        foreach (var component in components)
        {
            component.Update();
        }
    }
}

public class Component
{
    protected GameObject gameObject;

    public Component(GameObject gameObject)
    {
        this.gameObject = gameObject;
    }

    public virtual void Update()
    {

    }
}
```